# Outlier detection of time-series data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning, outliers

I have a pandas dataframe where I want to detect outliers on a single column. Please bear in mind that I am not experienced when it comes to data handling/cleaning.

The dataframe looks like this:

| Time | MW |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | 1234.0 |
| 2019-01-01 01:00:00 | 1234.5 |
| 2019-01-01 02:00:00 | 1235.2 |
| 2019-01-01 03:00:00 | 1235.1 |

You can see on the figure below that I do have some outliers, most noticably the one right above the 08:00:00 mark.

[image]

What I want is to detect these outliers and, instead of removing them, I want to modify them to be the mean of the 10 values that come before it (So the value of row 11 would be changed to the mean value of rows 1-10).

I have looked into calculating the z-score and finding outliers based on that, but it seems to focus on the standard deviation of the total dataset, instead of only a local range. You can see the code that I wrote for this below.

```
def dfCleaning(df):
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    z = np.abs(stats.zscore(df['MW']))

    for x in np.where((z > 3) | (z < -3)):
        for index in x:
            df.loc[index, 'MW'] = df.iloc[max(0, index-11) : max(1,index-1)]['MW'].mean()

    return df
```

So if there is a way to detect outliers based on a range of rows in a dataset (perhaps 50 rows above and below the row in focus), I would highly appreciate if someone could explain it to me.

Comment: Can you provide the dataset? It's difficult to troubleshoot outliers detection without a reproducible example.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot as I have signed an NDA with the company I'm collaborating with for a school project. However, the question is not so much about the end result, more about the method. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Sure, but it's easier with a dataset, can't your generate a dummy one that looks like it?

Comment: I added a table to illustrate the data. Does that work?

Comment: I generated a dummy example myself, I'll add it to my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
def zscore(s, window, thresh=3, return_all=False):
    roll = s.rolling(window=window, min_periods=1, center=True)
    avg = roll.mean()
    std = roll.std(ddof=0)
    z = s.sub(avg).div(std)   
    m = z.between(-thresh, thresh)
    
    if return_all:
        return z, avg, std, m
    return s.where(m, avg)

df['MW2'] = zscore(df['MW'], window=50)
```

##### full example:

```
N = 1000
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'MW': np.sin(np.linspace(0, 10, num=N))+np.random.normal(scale=0.6, size=N)})

z, avg, std, m = zscore(df['MW'], window=50, return_all=True)

ax = plt.subplot()

df['MW'].plot(label='data')
avg.plot(label='mean')
df.loc[~m, 'MW'].plot(label='outliers', marker='o', ls='')
avg[~m].plot(label='replacement', marker='o', ls='')
plt.legend()
```

Output:

[image]

With `thresh=2`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you friend. This may be a stupid question, but does this function replace the outliers or does it only detect them? I have a bit of trouble reading the code

Comment: If you use `return_all=False` it returns the Series with the replaced values (you stilll need to assign it!), if you use `return_all=True` it returns the computed components and you need to make the replacement yourself

Comment: Thank youvery much for your help! I finally got it to work

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample for remove outlier function. But I recommend split your data into times for ex. day to day or week to week apply remove outlier function and then concatenate it.

```
def remove_outliers(df_in, col_name):
        q1 = df_in[col_name].quantile(0.25)
        q3 = df_in[col_name].quantile(0.75)
        iqr = q3 -q1
        fence_low  = q1 -1.5 *iqr
        fence_high = q3 +1.5 *iqr
        df_out = df_in.loc[(df_in[col_name] > fence_low) & (df_in[col_name] < fence_high)]
        return df_out
```